# Should I use timestamp or date to store date to show dynamic time ago fucntion?

Tags: php, jquery, time, timestamp, timeago

I want to create dynamic timeago funtion with jquery timeago but I can do it with php time() because it is same for every server and I can handle it easily.But I heard that it is not recomended to store   timestamp(I get it from php time() function) it will be very high numbers in the 2038 and so on.

Also I watched facebook html codes I think they use timestamp also because I see this:

```
<abbr title="Sunday, July 01, 2016 at 12:24pm" data-utime="1468743808" class="timestamp livetimestamp">
<span class="timestampContent">about an hour ago</span></abbr>
```

data-utime it means they store timestamp?But why it is not recommended to store it?Is it true timestamp will be very high numbers in the future?

Comment: Seems like you're talking about the year 2038 problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Essentially, the timestamp will be higher than the maximum signed 32-bit integer value, but this should pose no problem at all as by then most if not all machines will 64-bit and be capable of handling 64-bit integers.

I recommend storing time as a timestamp, it's very easy to manipulate and doesn't have any real issues.

Comment: if I store timestamp on varchar (100)will there be any problem?

Comment: That should be OK, but BIGINT should be better for a timestamp.

Comment: @ebildude123 I want to learn what reason make BIGINT better than varchar?BIGINT take 64bit is not it?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter about the year, db timestamp type will occupy the same amount of bytes. You can use in JS new Date().getTime() does in fact return a UTC value, so it is a really helpful way to store and manage dates in a way that is agnostic to localized times. For the given example above they are using numeric repressntation of Timestamp.

Comment: Yes my question is should I store PHP time() date to varchar type column

Comment: It's a bad practice to go approach you want. Should be a corresponding date type on your database to keep Date type in other case you should care about transformation for you value to varchar and to date. Answer is that you should not use varchar to keep the Date type but Date type itself respecting you database.

Comment: no I didnt use it to keep date type I want to use it to keep just timestamp int value like 1468743808.Have you better solution to keep it?

Comment: Still not sure what do you need. I assumed you wanted to store timestamp value into database. If you just want to operate in JS you can declare variable this way var milliseconds = new Date().getTime(); I would say you should be more specific what you really want to do with your timestamp value.

Comment: I want to use timestamp because I dont want to deal with Localization problem ,And then I use jquery to make timestamp real date in user browser (it solve localiztion) and then I use my time ago function.In this case what you suggest about it?

Comment: Use an integer based type but not a char based type.

Comment: Okay but it is interesting for me that what is the advantage of int based type?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use numeric based types for numeric values not character based types.